# Format acronyms individually without being listed as a symbol in style=long

Tags: formatting, glossaries

I am using the glossary package (long style; glossarystle(listhypergroup)) and would like to format some of the entries like

```
\newacronym{abc}{\textsc{ABC}}{Alpha Beta Curious}
```

It generally works, however, they are listed in their own category in the `\makegloassaries` list as if they would be `\newacronym{hs}{$hs$}{hop size}`

> Acronyms
>
> Symbols | A | C | D | E | F | G | H | L | M | N | P | R | S | T | U
>
> Symbols
>
> ABC  Alpha Beta Curious
>
> hs hop size
>
> A
>
> C

I try to integrate them into the normal cateogry of the respective letter. And either remove the category symbols altogether or at least without the entries using `\textsc` or `\textit`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Maybe you can use the `sort` option of gloassaries.

Comment: I think that you may have accidentally created a second account to suggest an edit rather than editing with the account that asked the question. If this is the case then bring this to the attention of a moderator and they will help you merge the two account.